# scatter variable length data

Tags: c, mpi

I'm a new programmer to MPI. I'm writing a simple program to multiply a matrix by a vector. What I do is I first broadcast the vector to all the nodes and then send a bunch of rows of the matrix to each of the nodes using scatter.

My problem is, the number of rows in the array is not a multiple of the number of nodes available. So different nodes end up having different number of rows. At the moment I'm using point to point communication in a loop to do this. But I prefer if I could use MPI_Scatter instead. But MPI_Scatter only sends data of same length to all the nodes.

Is there anyway that I could use scatter to send data even when each of nodes get different size of data chunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MPI_Scatterv`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Scatterv.3.php) is made for exactly this case. You specify both a vector of sendcounts, as well as a vector of offset. It can be a bit tricky to properly create those, so there is an example:

```
int remainder = rows % comm_size;
int local_rows = (rows / comm_size)
if (comm_rank < remainder) {
    local_rows++;
}
int* sendcounts = NULL;
int* displacements = NULL;
double* data = NULL;
if (comm_rank = root) {
    data = ...;
    sendcounts = malloc(sizeof(int) * comm_size);
    displacements = malloc(sizeof(int) * comm_size);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < comm_size; i++) {
        sendcounts[i] = (rows / comm_size) * columns;
        if (remainder > 0) {
            sendcounts[i] += columns;
            remainder--;
        }
        displacements[i] = sum;
        sum += sendcounts[i];
    }
}
double* local_data = malloc(sizeof(*local_data) * local_rows * columns);
MPI_Scatterv(data, sendcounts, displacements, MPI_DOUBLE,
             local_data, local_rows * columns, MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```